# How do I pass in the google cloud project to the SHC BigTable connector at runtime?

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-dataproc, google-cloud-bigtable

I'm trying to access BigTable from Spark (Dataproc). I tried several different methods and SHC seems to be the cleanest for what I am trying to do and performs well.

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-bigtable-examples/tree/master/scala/bigtable-shc

However this approach requires that I put the Google cloud project ID in `hbase-site.xml` which means I need to build separate versons of the fat jar file with my spark code for each env I run on (prod, staging, etc.) which is something I'd like to avoid.

Is there a way for me to pass in the google cloud project id at runtime?

Comment: Interesting problem. In general, this problem is more about how HBase, Spark and shc manage this separate versions of hbase-site.xml than anything related to the Cloud Bigtable integration.

FYI, Cloud Bigtable supports HBase 2.0.0, which also has spark support.

Comment: @SolomonDuskis Do you have an example for me on how to talk to bigtable using the hbase2 api? I can find this one: https://github.com/apache/hbase/blob/master/hbase-spark/src/main/scala/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/spark/example/hbasecontext/HBaseBulkGetExample.scala but it still looks extremely clunky. I just want to point as an hbase table, get back a dataframe and work spark magic from there.

Comment: We don't have an HBase2 spark example, unfortunately.  FWIW, the Cloud Bigtable team focuses on Dataflow integration, and we don't have a great Spark integration yet, at least in terms of examples.

Comment: @SolomonDuskis I like dataflow, we use it in our streaming pipelines from pubsub (that's how the data gets into bigtable in the first place), but I also have data scientists working from notebooks that need a strait forward way to get at the bigtable data. Trying to figure out a non clucky/cumbersome way for them to work with our bigtable data.

Comment: Understood.  Perhaps our BigQuery integration might help: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-bigtable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the SHC library does not let you pass through hbase configs (looking in [here](https://github.com/hortonworks-spark/shc/blob/7fa435994e8233f3891e8675a301cd6101ff10ed/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/hbase/HBaseRelation.scala#L108)).

The easiest thing would be to run an init action that gets the VM's project id from [VM metadata](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/storing-retrieving-metadata) and sets it in `hbase-site.xml`. We are working on an initialization that does that and installs the Hbase client for Bigtable. Check out the in-progress [pull request](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dataproc-initialization-actions/pull/267), which would be a good starting point if you needed to write one immediately. Otherwise, I expect the PR to get merged in the next couple weeks.

Alternatively, consider adding an option in SHC for passing through properties to the HBaseConfiguration it creates. That would be a valuable feature for the broader community.